# How to extract every n-th row using array formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I try to extract every nth row of my datatable.
I know how to do it using INDIRECT and ROW formulas, I could try search the content and extract data this way (arrayformula + if(regexmatch())

But I wonder if there's a way to make it in one line. With no respect for it's content.

I tried INDEX, OFFSET, INDIRECT but these functions does not work with ARRAYFORMULA in the way I expected.

[image]

You can play with my data here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KUqXTvRlONbi5f3w3bVwVPBKfxWiSfiXsO5vHPWDiog/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use:

```
=FILTER(A5:A; MOD(ROW(A5:A)+1; 3)=0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! As I understand this formula "From the range A5:A, take a row for which row number +1 divided by 3 gives no remainder. "

Answer (score 6):

You could just use:

```
=QUERY(A5:A,"Select * skipping 3")
```

Or, since it's just a single column, we can omit `"Select *"`:

```
=QUERY(A5:A,"skipping 3")
```

This literally gives you the option to just get every nth row, 3 in this case.

[image]